# Sum custom objects like numbers (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, operator-overloading

I'm new on Javascript. I'm trying to do this exercise, but i cannot found anything to help me with that.

I created this object

```
var Foo = function(value) {
    this.val = value;
}
```

And now I need `sum` two `Foo objects` with `+ operator`.

```
var first = new Foo(2);
var second = new Foo(3);
var result = first + second; //should be 5
```

Do I have a way to overload `operator +` (like `c++`) , declare my `Foo object` as an `Integer` or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = first.val + second.val;
alert(result); // 5
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/czhE3/

**UPD**

OK, without val:

```
var Foo = function(value) {
    this.val = value;

    this.toString = function() {
        return this.val;
    }
}

var first = new Foo(2);
var second = new Foo(3);
var result = first + second;
alert(result); // 5
```

http://jsfiddle.net/czhE3/1/

Comment: I cannot use the .val on the exercise :(

Comment: Its an exercise from school. I need figure out a way to sum the numbers just using + operator. There is a way to return the .val on the constructor?

Comment: @Vlad thank you very much. now I see I can do this way too:

    var Foo = function(value) {
      return new Number(value);
    }

Answer (score 2):

As the previous people have mentioned you cannot override operators in javascript, but you could implement a valueOf which is the arithmetic version of a toString().
Add the follow code line:

```
Foo.prototype.valueOf = function () { return this.val; };
```

or

```
this.valueOf = function () { return this.val; };
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fJJL9/

Comment: thank you for show me another solution, this works too! its gratifying when people really helps when you trying to learn something new :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in Javascript to overload operators as in C++. The closest thing you can make is a sum function for your objects, like

```
function sum ( a, b ) { return a.value + b.value; }
```

Comment: I need use the + operator to sum. Maybe there is a way to declare my Foo object as an Integer?